# Jstree create_node function not working

Tags: javascript, jstree

I currently have a jstree setup and I want to use the create_node function, however nothing seems to be working and a lot of the code I'm finding online is for previous versions of jstree

Here's my one-liner of code that's not working:

```
$('#media-sidebar').jstree(true).create_node(parentID, {text: 'newNode', id: '123'});
```

I've checked many times that #media-sidebar is instantiated fine, and my parentID is correct at the time of making this call.  Simply put, nothing happens at all.  No errors or new nodes being created.

Does anyone know the updated syntax for creating a node?  I've tried about 5 different ways of doing this that I found here on stackoverflow but I think they are all deprecated in my most current version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have `"check_callback" : true` in your jstree `core` settings.

```
$('#media-sidebar')
    .jstree({
        "core": {
            "check_callback" : true
        }
    })
    .create_node(parentID, {text: 'newNode', id: '123'});
```